# What is a OnCreate method in android

Tags: android, oncreate

### I am new to android trying to understand what the below method does

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.filters); 
}
```

**My research** ::

- onCreate is used to start an activity
- super is used to call the parent class constructor
- setContentView is used to set the xml

---

But what is this all together -

- `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` .... why did that bundle come
  there, what is it
- What is that `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

**some explanation in layman terms would be helpful**

Comment: You can find all those answers in the documentation. [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) [Activities explained with examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you save the state of the application in a bundle (typically non-persistent, dynamic data in onSaveInstanceState), it can be passed back to onCreate if the activity needs to be recreated (e.g., orientation change). If the orientation changes(i.e rotating your device from landscape mode to portrait and vice versa), the activity is recreated and onCreate() method is called again, so that you don't lose this prior information. If no data was supplied, savedInstanceState is null.

For further information http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 13):

Bundle is used to save & recover state information for your activity. In instances like orientation changes or killing of your app or any other scenario that leads to calling of onCreate() again, the savedInstanceState bundle can be used to reload the previous state information.
Familiarity with [this article about Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) will help.

Answer (score 2):

Since the onCreate method is overridden, the super keyword is used to call the onCreate method of the base class. I think

Answer (score 2):

First `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` calls the method in the `superclass`
and saved `InstanceState` of the activity if any thing damage the activity so its saved in `instanceState` so when reload the activity it will be the same before.

Answer (score 1):

> super is used to call the parent class constructor

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` calls the `onCreate()` method, not the constructor, of the superclass.