# Change button background when clicked

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

I want a button that it has a background image and when I click that button,the button's background or color change (and we go to another activity.)
Tell me how can I make this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `xml` file and save it in one of the `drawable` folders in your project,let `bg.xml`,set this one as the background of your `Button`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_notpressed" />
</selector>
```

where `button_pressed` and `button_notpressed` are the images which you want to show on transition of the clicks and normal view of `button`

In your activity's `xml` file,set the background of the `button` as `bg.xml`

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"  <--! set it like this-->
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: Can you explain me selector(what do that do)

Comment: [Please see this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)

Comment: Excuse me but how or where can I download pdf that has every thing about android programming and ofcourse articles in developer.android.

Comment: I want a pdf or book that teach android regularly. I mean how did you learn android programming

Comment: Try developing some application, on the way you will come across issues and concepts, google them, if issues, then post them on stackoverflow ...anyways I will search for you for some pdf...mail me on my email id from my profile...I will send you one

Comment: Could you simply explain me oncreate bundle and override and other things in first part of java files.

Another question is that what is the difference between editable and string.

Simply please

Comment: [onCreate Description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538976/what-is-a-oncreate-method-in-android)