# Does Android Create instances of the Activity classes or how else does it work?

Tags: java, android, swing, android-activity, launcher

Having programmed for just over 6 months in Java i decided to give android a shot,but it looks like android merely uses the Java Syntax and all else differs

*Example:*
I can see under  `app/src/java/MainApplication...`
that 
The `Activity` `MainApplication` `extends Activity` and has
`onCreate()` methods etc , but what i don't get is how all this works, which method in the launcher activity runs first and how?

Can you draw an analogy between java Programs in `Jar` files ,say like how the class declared in `manifest` is launched and its `main` method runs and how android works?

I find the whole Android framework to be very different and confusing compared to the Java, Swing, AWT and event handling model of what i practiced so far, Please help!

How is `onCreate()` called without creating an instance of the class and calling the method on the Object, how is it called without an Object as the method is not `static` too?

PS:I'm taking Udacity's android course

Comment: This is a platform for concrete programming questions - not for "explain me the world because I don't want to study by myself" type of questions. There are so many good resources to learn how Android works - read them please.

Comment: Android apps. are more like an applet in this sense.  They have methods that are called automatically by the virtual machine.

Comment: @Carsten Still i would appreciate it if someone gave me the idea in a nutshell

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538976/what-is-a-oncreate-method-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it works as follows:

1. Application entry points such as activities are declared in the manifest file and it is bundled with the application APK.
2. The activity class is instantiated by name declared in the manifest, using reflection.
3. The class instance is set up (e.g. `Context`, `Configuration`) and its `onCreate()` and other lifecycle methods are called.

For code-level details, see e.g. [`performLaunchActivity()` in `ActivityThread`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2175).