# onCreate( ) method gets called without any reason on pressing button

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

In my app, First, I am verifying phone numbers by using phone authentication of `firebase`.

I am doing this process in the `OTPVerificationActivity` class. Every thing is working fine in this class, I am getting the `OTP` code also and the user gets signed in.

If the phone number is verified, then I am verifying the email by sending the verification email. I am doing this process in the `EmailVerificationActivity` class. In this class first, i am checking is the user exists or not. if the user is there, then I am logging out the user.

Then i create the account using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function. After this, i want to send a verification email to the user.

PROBLEM:- Now the problem is, after creating the account,`onCreate` method gets called again. Due to this, I am unable to send the verification email and the further task. So how to stop `onCreate` method from getting called again.

> NOTE :-
>   I tried to run only `EmailVerificationActivity` not `OTPVerificationActivity`.
>   In that case every thing was working properly. I was able to send verification email and also able to verify the user.
>   But when i am using the `OTPVerificationActivity`and `EmailVerificationActivity`  together i am getting this problem.
>   So please help me to solve this problem.

```
public class OTPVerificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String verificationID;

TextView messageTV;
EditText OTPET;

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
       signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

        verificationID = s;
        Log.i("onSend",s);
    }
};

String phoneNumber;

public void sendVerificationCode(View view)
{
    String code = OTPET.getText().toString();
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID,code);
    signInWithCredential(credential);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otpverification);

    messageTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
    OTPET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.OTPEditText);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
            {
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(OTPVerificationActivity.this,EmailVerification.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("firebaseAuth","user is not null");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    String message = "Please type the verification code sent to ";
    messageTV.setText(message+" " + "+91 " + getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNumber"));
    phoneNumber = "+91" + getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNumber");

    sendPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
    {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }
}

public void sendPhoneNumber(String number)
{
    Log.i("sendPhoneNumber","inside it");
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            number,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallBack
    );
    Log.i("sendPhoneNumber","outside it");
}

private void signInWithCredential(final PhoneAuthCredential credential)
{
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(!task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(OTPVerificationActivity.this, "Sign in Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(OTPVerificationActivity.this, "Phone number verified.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.i("FailedListener",e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}

> Below is the code of `EmailVerificationActivity` class.

```
public class EmailVerification extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText emailET, passwordET, confirmPasswordET;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

public void login(View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(EmailVerification.this,MainActivity.class));
}

public void submit(View view)
{
    String email = emailET.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordET.getText().toString();
    String confirmPassword = confirmPasswordET.getText().toString();

    if(!(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)))
    {
        if(password.equals(confirmPassword))
        {
            progressDialog.show();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        //acount created...
                        mAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Log.i("verificationEmail","send");
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                if(!EmailVerification.this.isFinishing())
                                {
                                    alertDialog.show();
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(EmailVerification.this, "Email send successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.i("verificationEmail","Not send");
                                //failed  to create account...
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(EmailVerification.this, "Failed to create account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //account not created...
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.i("taskNotSuccessful",task.getException().getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(EmailVerification.this, "Problem in creating account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Confirm Password is not same as Password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fields are empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_verification);

    Log.i("onCreate","inside it");

    initializeWidgets();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(EmailVerification.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Sending verification email.");

    builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(EmailVerification.this);
    builder.setTitle("Email Verification")
            .setMessage("We sent you a verification email, Please verify email before moving further.")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EmailVerification.this,SignInActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(R.style.MyProgressDialogStyle);
        }
    });

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
            {
                // user is signed up...
                Log.i("mAuthStateChanged","user is not null.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("mAuthStateChanged","user is null");
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

private void initializeWidgets()
{
    emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailEditText);
    passwordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordEditText);
    confirmPasswordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ConfirmPasswordEditText);
}
```

}

Comment: Please understand [what is onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538976/what-is-a-oncreate-method-in-android) Method in Android LifeCycle.

Comment: I think that createUserWithEmailAndPassword is the reason why onCreate is called again. So, how to stop it from do so....

Answer (score 0):

[image: oncreate]

This is the android life cycle. onCreate() will be called again, if your activity was destroyed due to release memory, explicitly killing and etc.

When you switch activities usually activities won't get killed. but it may be killed in some cases. so please move your codes from onCreate() to somewhere else.

You can not control android life cycle. It will happen anyway. therefore you need to obey them

Comment: thank you so much sir. But can you please tell what should i do. I mean where else should i write code other than `onCreate( )`.?